# Use pandas to import text file

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I need to make use of the data within a text file to plot a contour graph of multiple 'frames' that came from Stereophotogrammetry. This experiment looked at the vibration of a plate with and without boundary conditions to determine deformation.

I cant find a way for pandas to see columns and within the text file there are vertical spaces made up of '--------' lines. i have tried to convert to excel but I cant get rid of the '--------' lines.*

[Raw Text files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Gfj1IZdzU3nhKgyRhbi9aCr19L8Jp10C?usp=sharing)

[image]

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Gfj1IZdzU3nhKgyRhbi9aCr19L8Jp10C?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please add the raw text and what is expected to be loaded in DataFrame.

Comment: Might just be faster to use regular python to clean the text file, e.g., ```readlines()```, then ```split()``` the lines on tabs, delete the "----" lines, and then load them into a dataframe.

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice, i have uploaded the raw text files now. Sorry its my first time asking a question and couldn't find a way to upload directly and just took it as not being possible to share files.

Answer (score 1):

For reading text file as this one there are several options:

**(1) Drop unnecessary lines and split the rows:**

So first we are going to identify all lines which needs to be removed. Those contains - 'Stage', 'ID' etc

```py
import pandas as pd
raw_file = '26Hz.txt'
df_temp = pd.read_csv(raw_file, header=None)

dashes = df_temp[df_temp[0].str.contains(r'---', regex=True)].index
stages = df_temp[df_temp[0].str.contains(r'Stage', regex=True)].index
headers = df_temp[df_temp[0].str.contains(r'ID', regex=True)].index
```

The second step is drop rows identified in previous step, Now wre can split by consecutive spaces and set the column headers:

```py
df_temp = df_temp.drop(dashes)
df_temp = df_temp.drop(stages)
df_temp = df_temp.drop(headers)
df_temp = df_temp[0].str.split(r'\s+', expand=True)
df_temp.columns = ['ID', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'DX', 'DY', 'DZ', 'D']
```

result:

|  | ID | X | Y | Z | DX | DY | DZ | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2000 | -0.2403 | -373.755 | 66.815 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2001 | 65.4933 | -361.248 | 73.5688 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1005 | 232.82 | -343.124 | 96.7302 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 1002 | 224.64 | -261.401 | 93.0053 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 1004 | 230.751 | -203.746 | 96.4308 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

7199 rows × 8 columns

**(2) Find the starts and endings**

This approach is a bit more complicated and might lead to unexpected results. So it will need better validation that works as expected.

With this approach you can trace the source of the rows.

After reading the file we are searching for the starting and endings for the tables:

```py
df_temp = pd.read_csv(raw_file, header=None)
ixs = df_temp[df_temp[0].str.contains(r'ID ')].index
ixs_e = df_temp[df_temp[0].str.len() == 52].index
```

Then iterating through all indexes in order to read portion of the file:

```py
dfs = []

for i, ix in enumerate((zip(ixs,ixs_e))):
    start = ix[0]  + 2*i
    end = ix[1]-3
    df_temp = pd.read_csv(raw_file, sep=r'\s+', skiprows=start, nrows=end)
    df_temp['source'] = i
    dfs.append(df_temp)
    display(df_temp)
    
pd.concat(dfs)
```

dfs[0]

|  | ID | X | Y | Z | DX | DY | DZ | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2000 | -0.2403 | -373.755 | 66.815 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2001 | 65.4933 | -361.248 | 73.5688 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1005 | 232.82 | -343.124 | 96.7302 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1002 | 224.64 | -261.401 | 93.0053 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1004 | 230.751 | -203.746 | 96.4308 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

72 rows × 8 columns

in:

- `dfs` - you have list of all DataFrames read
- `pd.concat(dfs)` concatenation of all DataFrames

Data cleaning and validation is needed.